# Viewing all file attributes in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows-7, file-attributes

Where is the File Attributes column in Windows 7? I desperately want to see all the extended attributes -- System, Append-only, Immutable, nodump, etc -- but just am not seeing any besides the usual RO/Archive/Hidden...

I am using a Samba share to view these properties. `attrib` does not seem to display them either.

Answer (score 5):

In a folder right click on the *Name* field and choose more.

Under *more* you can check/uncheck different fields, including attributes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By pressing:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> all columns will automatically fit to the text-length in that column...

For music folders you need diffent attributes to be shown. For folders containing photographs you different attributes, for data you need different attributes. And so on.. This can be done, but I would like an easier way. There are SO MANY different attributes lately, showing them ALL in one big list is really not a good idea...

btw,

In a dialogbox, containing only photographs, it would be handy to show this folder's thumbnails,
rather than to have this done manually each and every time..