# Windows 7 Explorer: How to change the columns displayed for file attributes?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Please see shots below.

In some cases, explorer only shows the columns related to media files (title, album), when I just want the standard file listing (so I can sort on file date...)

How to accomplish this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Right click on a column header][1] to get a popup dialog to add more.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/304781/viewing-all-file-attributes-in-windows-7-explorer

Comment: @jdh  In win7, right clicking on col header has no effect, at least in media view...

Answer (score 3):

Windows generates according to file types the folder properties. In the second image, you have in that folder music files, or media files in general, therefore you see those details. In this case you have to "convert" the media folder, to "normal" folder. To do that, right-click on the folder you want to make changes Properties > Customize, and under "What kind of folder do you want?" > "Optimize this folder for:", select "General Items".
You can alternatively select "Also apply this template to all subfolders", and click Apply/Ok to save changes. But, you also have to know that by doing this, you will not have some buttons next to organize, in the menu bar, like Play selected, Play all, etc. 
To remove undesired details, click Alt > View > Choose details... and select the one you want in that folder.
But you have to know that changes do no apply to all the folders or files, but to the folder(or/and subfolders) and files you are making the changes.
For more read: [Windows Explorer Column Heading Permanent???](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-column-heading-permanent/0273d101-b336-4228-a82b-52b3d102628d), [choose details for multiple folders at one time](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/choose-details-for-multiple-folders-at-one-time/76561f9b-b28c-4a82-8e7e-13e761939cf4)

Comment: Thanks! That works for an actual folder, but for the "virtual" folders (like Downloads, in the 2nd shot above), there is no Customize option. What to do?

Comment: That happens because what you are seeing is a shortcut of the folder Downloads. Right click on the shortcut > open folder location. Then after that, you follow the same steps like all other folders.

Comment: Erlis, yes, that works, but is an extra hop, every time I am in that folder...

Comment: You can find Downloads folder also on C:\Users\<username>, and make changes there (that is the default location anyway...)
If you found the solution, please mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the row of attributes (for instance, in your screenshot, you'd right click next to "album") and click "more" at the bottom of the mini menu that pops up. from there you can choose all the attributes you want

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Steps:

Start menu | type: downloads
right click on the "downloads" entry that appears in the start menu
Properties | Customize:  General files, apply to subfolders

tada

Answer (score 0):

highlight (single click) on the folder (parent folder with subfolders) , go to Tools in menu bar, select Folder Options, select View tab, click Apply to Folders. This will apply format (the column heading details and folder view) to all subfolders.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Clicking Apply to Folders will apply the current view, for example detailed list or icons, to all folders of the same type, but only folders of the same type. So for example if you're in a folder for documents, it will only apply it to other folders with documents and not to folders with for example music. And as far as I know, this won't change the columns that are visible in the detailed view, it will only change if you're in detailed view or not.